# Sonar Java - Format strings within lambda expressions cause 'An 'int' is expected rather than a !Defered type!' critical issues

Tags: java, sonarqube, string-formatting

The Sonar Java plug-in contains a rule

> Printf-style format strings should not lead to unexpected behavior at
>   runtime (squid:S2275)

This rule produces critical Sonar issues:

> An 'int' is expected rather than a !Defered type!

These are raised when it encounters a string formatting expression within a lambda function when one or more of the parameters being formatted is in the lambda's parameter list. Example:

```
    private final PercentTracker<ExtractDataTuple> zeroDurationCounter =
        new PercentTracker<>(
            ExtractDataTuple::startTimeSameAsEndTime,
            (hitCount, total, percent) -> LOG.info(String.format(
               "Emitted %d/%d segments with no duration  %,.2f%%", hitCount, total, percent))
        );
```

The tracker class constructor's third parameter is a function with arguments int, int and float returning void.  This has been supplied via a lambda.

Should the Sonar rule be determining the types of the lambda parameters?  If not, ow can I resolve the Sonar issue by changing the code?  Correct me if I am wrong (long-time C# coder, new to Java) but I don't appear to be able to specify the argument types for the lambda explicitly.  Should I formally cast the parameters within the format call to the types specified by the format specifiers?

Comment: Could you precise which version of the java plugin you are using ? This is a flaw in semantic analysis (type inference is hard to get correctly) and so that  is why the type of your variable is not resolved properly. (hence the !DeferedType! instead of int)

Comment: Java plugin is version 3.14.

Comment: Then I do recommend you to uprgrade to latest version of the java analyzer (4.1 at time of writing with  4.2 about to be released) as a lot of improvement as been made regarding type inference and especially on lambdas and method references.

Comment: Ok, will try latest.  Not sure if we can run the required version of Sonar to support the latest Java plugin though, but that's not an issue to discuss here.

Comment: Pleased to report that with Sonar 5.6.1 and Java plugin 4.2 the issue reported in my post no longer exists.